# Using Firebase Firestore in a web app, can i exclude certain fields from being returned?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I could not find anything in the docs, but say I perform a query such as

```
const snapshot = await jobsRef.where('status', '==', STATUS_ACTIVE).get();
```

Could exclude certain fields from being returned for this "job"?
There are certain fields in the "job" document that should remain private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to retrieve certain fields and as Doug mentioned above, you can separate the fields in different collection or sub-collection.

If you do not wish to redesign your database structure, you can alternatively use Firebase Cloud Functions in which you can fetch the required document, filter the data received and return the required fields to user. Hence user won't be able to see complete Document either.

Though this will obviously increase your costs as you will be using Cloud Functions.
Though it's really effective to way filter and Verify who is retrieving the data.

Comment: Ah cool that could work. So I can basically configure an endpoint thats a function i can call?

Comment: @strangeQuirks yes you can use Firebase Callable functions

Answer (score 2):

For web and mobile clients, it's not possible to exclude certain fields from a query.  When you query a document, it will always deliver all of the fields for all of the matching documents.  Security rules will not help you with this.

For cases where there are public and private fields to separate, you should make two different collections and protect them with different security rules.  You can choose either two top-level collections:

```
/jobs-public/{id}
/jobs-private/{id}
```

Or you can use subcollections:

```
/jobs/{id}/public/{id}
/jobs/{id}/private/{id}
```

In either case, you will have to make sure that the user can only read the documents that they are allowed to by your requirements.